# Which protocol does Mongo extension for PHP use for communication with the server?

Tags: php, mongodb

Which protocol does the **Mongo** extension for PHP use for communication with the server?

I suspect it is **binary** but I want to know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses [BSON](http://www.bsonspec.org), which is binary.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was JSON. Thanks.